# Ckeditor in reviews not showing html in frontend Opencart

Tags: php, html, ckeditor, opencart, review

Ckeditor in reviews not showing html in frontend Opencart !

I did it  from /admin/view/template/catalog/review_form.tpl

IN

```
<td><textarea name="text" cols="60" rows="8"><?php echo $text; ?></textarea>
```

Added : `id="description1"`

```
<td><textarea name="text" cols="60" rows="8" id="description1"><?php echo $text; ?></textarea>
```

and before `<?php echo $footer; ?>`

I Added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="view/javascript/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
CKEDITOR.replace('description1', {
 filebrowserBrowseUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
 filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
 filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
 filebrowserUploadUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
 filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
 filebrowserFlashUploadUrl: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>'
});
//--></script>
```

But the problem is in front end is showing the pure html code

insted of a link or image as [google](http://google.com)
is showing `<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>`

Any help?

Thanks

Edited on 25/10/13

I did it

```
<td><textarea name="text" cols="60" rows="8" id="description1"><?=htmlentities($text)?></textarea>
```

But without success

Answer (score 0):

You should html-encode the text you want to put into the editor:

```
<textarea name="text" cols="60" rows="8"><?=htmlentities($text)?></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg , but I cant find a way to do it ! Any help ?

Comment: You have to use `htmlentities()` function

Comment: Refael, sorry, but I need at least 2k reputation to review Suggested Edits. So you can add your changes as update to your question.

Comment: Don't you try to fill it with javascript function `insertHtml()`? http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#insertHtml

Comment: `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.insertHtml( '<p>This is a new paragraph.</p>' );`

Comment: tks for your help , but I dont know where I can put this code !